# Chain jumps up and down when freewheeling and back cog moves back and forward on my new bike

Tags: road-bike, shimano, chain

The chain jumps up and down when freewheeling. The chain sometimes jumps off the front cog. The cause it seems comes from the back cog going backwards and forward continually when I am freewheeling.

Comment: Check the rear axle - it should not move in the frame at all.

Comment: how come the chain is moving when freewheeling?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing spacer when mounting the cassette. Locking nut loose? Can be dangerous to ride that way. Can you remove the back wheel and post some pictures?